# Application (sometimes) crashes on PlaySound()

Tags: c++, playsound

I'm writing a game where player picks coins. Picking a coin there is supposed to be a sound, I use PlaySound to play *.wav file. It works. But sometimes (7/10 attempts) app just crushes. I have no idea why sometimes is works and sometimes it doesn't.

The interesting thing is when I run the app in debug mode it works perfectly

What can cause the problem and how can it be fixed?

And also can you recommend another way to play wav? (As simple as that (Using one-two functions))

I've tried to use PlaySoundA, sndPlaySound all of the variations - the same result

tried to read wav directly from file and save it in memory - the same result

```
//This sample checks if there a coin on the right 
void Player::step_right() {
    if (check_right()) {
      sndPlaySound(TEXT("D:\\projects\\s.wav"), SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
      //PlaySoundA(TEXT("D:\\projects\\s.wav"), nullptr, SND_FILENAME | SND_ASYNC);
      //sndPlaySound(buffer, SND_MEMORY || SND_ASYNC);
      netWorth++;
      steps+=10;      
    }
    cur->X++;
  }
```

upd: 
I use MinGW

Console output after crush: Process finished with exit code -1073741819 (0xC0000005)

Here is the Player class specification:

```
 class Player {
     private:
        Point* cur;              // Current coords
        Point post;              // Last coords
        int steps;               // Remaining steps
        int netWorth;            // Picked coins
        void (Player::*m[4])();  // Array of movement functions pointers

        // Movement
        void step_right();
        void step_left();
        void step_up();
        void step_down();

        // Coins checking
        bool check_right();
        bool check_left();
        bool check_up();
        bool check_down();

     public:
        Player();
        Point* Getcur() { return cur; }
        void Move(void (Player::*t)());
        bool isOutofSteps();
        auto ReturnSomeArray() { return m; }
        int GetNet(); //Networth
        void display_player_info();
  };
```

I also have Action_Listener class which has

```
map<int, void (Player::*)()> m;
```

Depending on a keycode I send a function pointer to `void Player::Move(void (Player::*t)())`

here:

```
if (m.find(event) != m.end() && !player->isOutofSteps()) {
      void (Player::*t)() = m[event];

      player->Move(t);

      unsigned int (Drawer::*y)() = drawhandlers[event];
      drawer->Draw_Hero(y);
      player->display_player_info();
    } else if(player->isOutofSteps()){
      terminal_print(2, 2, "You're out of steps");
      return;
    }
```

Move function:

```
 void Player ::Move(void (Player::*t)()) {
    post = *cur;
    (this->*t)();
    steps--;    
  }
```

Comment: You should add more code (where the class is used and how, at least), some link to the library would help too and, eventually, the error codes or warnings you could have. Specifying the compiler usually gives a lot of information, as why it works when in debug mode (compilers do different optimisation when you compile in release mode).

Comment: You haven't provided a [mcve] so one can only guess.   My guess ....  The third argument of `PlaySound()` is normally formed using bitwise operations  e.g.   `SND_MEMORY | SND_ASYNC` whereas you are using logical operations `SND_MEMORY || SND_ASYNC`.      Also, `SND_MEMORY | SND_ASYNC` is a bad idea - look at blog from a Microsoft developer at https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/larryosterman/2009/02/19/playsoundxxx-snd_memory-snd_async-is-almost-always-a-bad-idea/

Comment: @VictorHMartin Gave some more code and information. What can you say? What information could also help?

Comment: @Peter I know that. As you can see it's commented, I tried it just to find out if it works somehow different, but every combination faces the same problem